# Network Routing through Proxy to VPN

Tags: network, firewalls, vpn, proxy

(This is *somewhat* of an extension [to this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117564/vpn-server-in-a-router).)

I've come to enjoy (yes, I know) using a VPN for all of my internet usage (specifically [Freedome](https://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global/freedome)), but I don't have a lot of money to buy subscriptions for every single device. I'd like to just purchase one subscription, install it on a single computer/server, and route all traffic through that LAN proxy. I believe this would have the additional advantage that I can set up a firewall on this machine and protect my whole network.

I'm rather new to network security though, and I haven't tested any of this yet. Is there a better method that could be less of a bottleneck? Or does this sound like a good approach for routing traffic?

**Update:** In the case of Freedome, it appears that this would be a breach of the usage terms:

> If the Software and/or its services are shared through a network or the Software is used to filter traffic at servers, firewalls or gateways, you must have a license for either scanning capacity or for the total number of users whom the Software provides services to. *Source: [Freedome License Terms](https://www.f-secure.com/en/web/legal/terms/software)*

Comment: I would not encourage you to game the system like this.

Comment: @Limit Fair point, thanks. It does appear that this is in violation of terms at least for the software I was considering using. I've made a note of it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you've discovered, firstly you need to find a VPN that allows you to do that in the terms and conditions.

But in general terms, this is a common way of working with VPN's, just not so much with the type of VPN you are using. VPN's are commonly used to connect "branch offices" to a head office in enterprises. In this case, the router is the VPN end-point rather than each PC since the latter would be very inefficient.

In your case, the *best* way is to get hold of a VPN that supports being an end point (VPN termination) rather than just being a VPN "passthrough". Of course, the router needs to be able to terminate the type of VPN your service provider supports - OpenVPN, IPSEC or whatever.

If you can't do that, you need to set up a computer as the VPN end point *and* as a router. Then connect the other computers on the "inside" of the router. There are lots of ways to do that but the most performant way would need a computer with 2 network cards, Linux can be used to create a router and there are several versions of Linux that are pre-configured for that purpose.